# Google custom search is not showing correct number of data

Tags: search

I am facing an issue regarding Google custom search. What is happening the total number of result is not same the paging.

Comment: Read [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/customsearch/troubleshooting-and-bugs/PngSBJW1Huk) conversation. Please update you question providing more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. This is a function. IF you have premium  account you can contact to Google support.